# unbold acronyms in the list

Tags: acronyms

How do I unbold the acronyms from the list of acronyms? 
I am using the acronym package. I need to produce the list of acronyms but without bold acronyms next to their full forms.

Comment: Redefine `\acsfont` as described in the documentation? (`texdoc acronym`)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @AndrewCashner probably not

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the macro `\aclabelfont`. It's default definition is

```
\newcommand*\aclabelfont[1]{\textbf{\acsfont{#1}}}
```

The naive redefinition just leaving `\textbf{}` away, i.e.,

```
\renewcommand*\aclabelfont[1]{\acsfont{#1}}
```

might or might not work: it works if you use the optional argument of the `acronym` environment like this

```
\begin{acronym}[foo]
  \acro{foo}{bar}
\end{acronym}
```

but doesn't work if you don't use it

```
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{foo}{bar}
\end{acronym}
```

The `acronym` package uses different lists for both cases. In the second case it uses a `description` list which also  bolds its items. So if you don't want to change all `description? lists a redefinition that works for both cases would be

```
\renewcommand*\aclabelfont[1]{\textnormal{\acsfont{#1}}}
```